# login doesn't work after update

Tags: updates, login

I did a clean install of 19.10 on my HP desktop.  After running software updater and rebooting it goes to the login screen.  I type in the password and it won't login, just shows the login screen again. Tried it a couple times with the same result.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it say "invalid password" in an angry color? Or is login successful, but the desktop session crashes back to the login screen?

Comment: It must be the latter.  No error, just a quick flash and then it's back to login. Since it's a "nuke and pave" I tried the 19.10 PopOS for a lark and it survived the update.

Comment: I'm not sure what "it survived the update" means in the context of replacing with a completely different distro. But a fix won't seem to help you anymore and Pop!OS is off-topic here, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: That's fine.  Another question seems to have the answer.  FWIW, PopOS is based on Ubuntu and I was referring to the fact that initial install worked fine, but the issue started after initial update.